# Python Setup.py giving ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, installation, pip

I have been trying to use this library: latbin
(https://pypi.python.org/pypi/latbin)

pip didn't work
Then downloaded the files and used : python setup.py install
Changed current directory in that folder (windows)

```
  C:\...\latbin-0.1.4.tar\dist\latbin>python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 5, in <module>
    import latbin
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'latbin'
```

directory structure using the same as downloaded.

Btw, this is the setup.py code:

```
import os
os.chdir("C:/.../latbin-0.1.4.tar/dist/latbin/")
from distutils.core import setup
#from setuptools import setup, find_packages
import latbin

packages = ['latbin']
install_requires = ['numpy>=1.8','scipy>=0.14','pandas>=0.14']
ext_modules = []

setup(
    name='latbin',
    author="Tim Anderton, Dylan Gregersen",
    author_email='<quidditymaster@gmail.com>;<dylan.gregersen@utah.edu>',
    url="https://github.com/astrodsg/latbin",
    license="3-clause BSD style license",
    description="Python lattice binning package for large data",
    long_description=open("README.rst").read(),
    classifiers=["Development Status :: 3 - Alpha",
                 "Intended Audience :: Developers",
                 "Intended Audience :: Science/Research",
                 "License :: OSI Approved :: BSD License",
                 "Natural Language :: English",
                 "Programming Language :: Python",
                 "Topic :: Scientific/Engineering :: Mathematics",
                 "Topic :: Scientific/Engineering :: Physics"],
    platforms='any',
    version=latbin.__version__,
    #packages=find_packages(),
    packages=packages,
    ext_modules=ext_modules,
    install_requires=install_requires,
    )
```

Comment: It looks almost as if you didn't extract the tarball completely. Extract **all of the files** in the tarball, then run `setup.py` in the top-level directory. You can also tell pip to install the downloaded tarball. What error message did `pip` produce when you tried to install the first time?

Comment: And for background: the current script directory is added to the Python path, so the `latbin` package in the same location as the `setup.py` file can be imported directly. Provided it is there of course.

Comment: You can't relocate ram to ram(default dir = "/tmp"), check @MartijnPieters comments.

Comment: Are you certain you have downloaded the right files? When I download latbin the file `setup.py` doesn't have the first two lines. Also, why aren't you using pip?

Comment: Yes, I have tried PIP... same error....
And the lines I added just to make the things work on current directory....as it was not getting the files I guessed.

Comment: Finally found the real solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42664276/cant-install-spacy-on-winpython-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-semver it's from a bug

Answer (score 0):

Well it's not necessarily the answer to this question... but it worked in Anaconda Distribution, previously I was trying with WinPython and still there it doesn't work.

Finally found the right answer:

[It was a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42664276/cant-install-spacy-on-winpython-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-semver)